# Scala string to date conversion

Tags: scala, datetime-format

I have a string format of a date but which is from a csv file:
20200520T0200 , assuming its in the format of (yyyyMMdd/T/24-hour format).

I have managed to read the lines in the csv file and seperated it into an arraybuffer.

My question is i cannot format the string into a date, as i need to use the date to calculate some values. As i will use this formatter to format all the values of the first element of my arraybuffer which is the time with strings of "20200406T0300, etc, etc, etc".

Currently i have tried using DateTimeFormatter,

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqvCP.png)
    import java.io.File

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddaH")
val date_int_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val last_extract_value= "20200530T0200"
val string_to_date = dtf.parse(last_extract_value)


val rows = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()

val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile("D:/Scala/Testtt/src/main/scala/testData.csv")
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines.drop(10)) {
  rows += line.split(",").map(_.trim)

}
for (row <- rows) {
  println(s"${row(0)}|${row(1)}")
}
```

Comment: *format the string into a date* makes no sense, which makes the entire question unclear. You *parse* a string into some date-time object and/or your format *the date-time object into a string*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's a standard DateTime format, someone either removed or added something to it. It looks like `ISO DATE` but `ISO` is in format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm ...`

Edit: @OleV.V. kindly clarified the format as the basic form of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) format

You have a few options

1. Either get rid of that T and parse it with `SimpleDateTimeFormat`

   val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
   val f = format.parse("20200520T0200".replaceAll("T", "")) //Wed May 20 02:00:00 GMT 2020
2. Or define a custom formatter and parse it into what ever [`time object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) floats your boat.

   val customFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm");
   val q = LocalDateTime.parse("20200520T0200", customFormatter)

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped me solve the problem .

Comment: By all means avoid `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s a notorious troublemaker of a class, and long outdated. And there’s no reason whatsoever why the modern `DateTimeFormatter` cannot do the job. Suggestion no. 2) is fine, also the choice of `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for the info! I didn't know the compact format existed and was standardized. Edited the answer with the link, credited to you